# What are the drawbacks of using WithAttributeFiltering() in EVERY registrations of my interfaces?

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using a rule to register all the interfaces in my solution:

```
    public void RegisterDefaultNamingConventionInterfacesForAssembly(string assembly,
        string namespaceFilter)
    {
        // Default Rule => Foo : IFoo
        _builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(assembly))
            .Where(t =>
            {
                var existImplementation = t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains(namespaceFilter) &&
                                          t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name) != null;

                return existImplementation;
            })
            .As(t => { return t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name); })
            .WithAttributeFiltering();
        ;
    }
```

Some of the classes **(not all)** uses a custom attribute based on ParameterFilterAttribute. That's why I need to register with **WithAttributeFiltering()**.

What are the drawbacks of registering every single class with WithAttributeFiltering() even if many of them does not make use of the custom defined ParameterFilterAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to opt in to WithAttributeFiltering is because it's a performance cost. Every time the filtering is used in a resolve operation, work has to be done to execute the filtering - work that wouldn't otherwise need to happen. If you're building a small system or something that isn't performance-intensive, you probably won't notice the difference. If you're building something where performance is important, opting in *only* on the things that need it will help you achieve better performance.